# Нужно из двух текстовых полей отправить post запрос серверу C#

Tags: c#, post, textbox, отправка

Нужно из двух текстовых полей отправить post запрос серверу C#
в первом textbox-е - url
во втором - файл.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы такими же параметрами передавались на сервер.

> new WebClient().UploadString("stackoverflow.com",POST, @"C:\Users\test.txt");

Пример походу нельзя реализовать.

> new WebClient().UploadString("textbox1",POST, "textbox2");

Не знаю, как можно это реализовать.

Comment: с русским языком все плохо)

Comment: мы заметили, что плохо

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под `серверу C#`?

Comment: `UploadString(textBox1.Text, "POST", textBox2.Text)` ?